# How to create a 2D grid type view to get and set string to each cell?

Tags: android, user-interface, gridview, tableview

[image: view to make]

> I want to create a view like the image where each cell will be populated by a 2D array string. Each cell will contain edittext so that user can provide input.
>
> I have tried to use GridLayout, GridView and TableView but I couldn't get any specific cell at (i,j) position to get and set string.
>   How can I do that, any idea, tutorial or code snippet will great.

Comment: Make a custom view by extending TextView to show the 2D array?

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you think about creating GridView inside a GridView?
You will have a GridView with the number of columns and rows you need, each view inside the Grid will be another GridView that will consists of several EditTexts. You will need 2 adapters for that thing, one for every GridView.

Edit with code:
Be aware that it is a try version, adjust it to you'r needs.

MainActivity layout:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</GridView>
```

item_grid_parent:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view_child"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</GridView>
```

item_grid_child:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    stringList.add("a");
    stringList.add("b");

    stringList.add("c");
    stringList.add("d");


    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view_parent);
    gridView.setNumColumns(3);
    GridParentAdapter gridParentAdapter = new GridParentAdapter(this,
    stringList); 

    gridView.setAdapter(gridParentAdapter);
}
```

GridParentAdapter:

```
public class GridParentAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;
private GridView gridViewChild;

private List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();


public GridParentAdapter(Activity context, List<String> items){
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return items.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup
parent) { 
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService
    (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_parent, parent
    gridViewChild = (GridView) convertView.findViewById
    (R.id.grid_view_child);

    final GridChildAdapter gridChildAdapter = new
    GridChildAdapter(context, items, this); 
    gridViewChild.setNumColumns(4);
    gridViewChild.setAdapter(gridChildAdapter);


    return convertView;
}

public void setItemChar(int position, String character){
    items.set(position, character);
}
```

}

GridChildAdapter:

```
public class GridChildAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private EditText editText;
private GridView gridViewParent;
private Context context;
private List<String> character;
private GridParentAdapter gridParentAdapter;

public  GridChildAdapter(Context context, List<String> character
,GridParentAdapter gridParentAdapter){
    this.context = context;
    this.character = character;
    this.gridParentAdapter = gridParentAdapter;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return character.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return character;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup
parent) {                      
    LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService                  
    (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid_child, parent,
    false); 

    editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    editText.setText(character.get(position));
    editText.setClickable(true);
    editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
                InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager) 
                context.getSystemService
                (Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                im.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
                editText.requestFocus();

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int
        i,int i1, int i2) { 

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int
        i1, int i2) { 
            if (editText.getText().toString() != "null") {
               gridParentAdapter.setItemChar
               (position,charSequence.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

public String getEditTextValue(EditText editText){
    String string = "";
    if(editText != null){
        string =  editText.getText().toString();
    }
    return string;
   }
}
```

Comment: I am kind of liking your answer but it will be great if you extend the answer or show some example cause it's not clear till now.

Comment: See the edited version. Don't forget  it is just a sample(you need to click two times on the edit text you want to change). I just wanted to bring the code of the idea of GridView inside GridView.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Though it is not what i wanted, i am marking it as correct answer because it showed a way to accomplish the grid. May be i am going to use RecyclerView with StaggerdLayoutManager in the same you described with GridView.

Comment: I would like to see you'r code when it will be ready, sounds very interesting! so whenever you want, you can send me the code via email. thanks for marking as correct!